# Vim, erasing multiple spaces used as indentation

Tags: indentation

I've been struggling with this topic for a little more than i'd like to admit but here it is:

I've set my vim (~/.vimrc) to indent using 4 spaces using

```
:set expandtab
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
```

Whenever I want to detete one of these groups I have to remove every one of the spaces. I thought vim would recognize this and remove them all like they were a single tab. Could anyone shed some light?

thks in advance :3

Comment: Note that there exists another workflow: I prefer to leave vim indent by itself (in C++ it's possible at least). And when I really need to change the indentation manually, I use either `<<` and `>>` in normal mode, or `CTRL-D` and `CTRL-T` in insert mode. In the end, I never need `<BS>` nor `<del>` to remove `&sw` leading space characters.

Answer (score 3):

You may prefer either or both of the following options:

```
set smarttab
set softtabstop=4
```

The primary difference between these two options in your case (where `expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4`) is whether the "backspace deletes 4 spaces" behavior works only at the beginning of lines (as with `smarttab` only) or everywhere, aligning to tab stops (as with `softtabstop=4`).  For other values of `expandtab`, `tabstop`, `shiftwidth` the behavior is much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

The other choice is to just use '<<' or '>>' to shift the line left or right.  That should give you exactly the behavior you want from anywhere on the line.  You can of course delimit a group of lines by moving to an opening or closing '[', '(' or '{', and doing '<%' or '>%' to shift a range of lines.

Of course other movement types work as well:

```
 >L
 >/foo^M
```

and others.

Comment: Or you could use `ctrl-t` and `ctrl-d` in insert mode. (see `:help i_ctrl-t` and `:help i_ctrl-d`)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @Octaviour! :)